# how to change the self-loop properties in jgraphx?

Tags: jgraphx

When I draw an edge that has the same source and target vertex it shows as a loop, and this loop is drawn always on the right of the vertex
that becomes a problem when there is and edge that exits or enters from the right too

[the loop that has 6/9 in this image presents the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyNTx.jpg)

Is there a way to manage the position where the loop is drawn?
I have tried to change it using `mxConstants.STYLE_LOOP` but still nothing.

Comment: Please include examples of what you do

Comment: hello @s.lenders here is a graph that i did to show you the problem exactly, i want that loop that has 6/9 to be drawn on the left

Comment: Please add it to the main post so the community of SO can try and answer your question as best as possible